# HERMS waterproof hole in heat exchanger

Tags: equipment, water-heater

I'm in the initial phase of my HERMS project, and I'm struggling to come up with an elegant solution to waterproofing the hole where my copper pipe will enter the hot liquor tank. Ideally I'd like some kind of thru-hull (below) that has fittings on either side I can attach the pipe to, but for the life of me I can't find one. What is the typical solution for this problem?

[image: thru-hull]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Electric Brewery](http://www.theelectricbrewery.com/hot-liquor-tank?page=4) has a step-by-step guide for mounting a valve and quick disconnect to the kettle wall.

To summarize, pass a 1/2" threaded nipple through a hole in the kettle. On the outside, secure with a lock nut and high temperature silicone o-ring. On the inside, secure with an FPT compression fitting. The stainless tubing is connected on the inside to the compression fitting.

Comment: Also, sites like [Brewers Hardware](http://www.brewershardware.com/Weldless-Fittings/), [Northern Brewer](http://www.northernbrewer.com/shop/cooler-bulkhead.html), &c. have pre-configured weldless fittings that should fit the bill.